# Кнопка сброса кеша web сайта для мобильного Safari

Tags: javascript, php, css

Возможно ли сделать кнопку сброса кеша сайта? Речь конечно же о CSS который не во всех браузерах скидывается силой мысли

В хедере строка

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=$css . $time. '&theme='.  $_COOKIE['theme']?>">

// Тут $css = "main.css";
// $time = "?t=1667680484";
// $_COOKIE['theme'] = "название темы";

// На выходе:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/neo_tables.css?t=1667680484&theme=winter">
```

Все прекрасно работает и браузер генерирует вполне понятную и динамически меняющийся адрес стилей, но вот в мобильном сафари (а мне вот почему то он милее всех) не работает.

Приходится лезть в настройки, чистить кеш, авторизоваться и лишь потом наслаждаться результатом. Не удобно

Вопрос - можно ли реализовать на сайте кнопку сброса кеша для дальнейшей имитации нажатия ее JS-ом для незамедлительного результата?

Если есть более изящный механизм (кроме перестать пользоваться мобильным сафари) буду рад стать умнее!

Comment: А если создать роут типа Route::get('/css_(version).css', { return get_file_content($pathToCss) ;}) Ну или каким-то образом включить time в имя файла /css_1667680484.css&theme=dark

Comment: Увы не мой вариант, так как сайт на процедурке. Но вариант очень интересный)